# I can't transfer all the struct of the temp file to leave details file

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
struct leavedetails {
    char staffid[10];
    char leavefrom[15];
    int leavebalance;
    char reason[20];
    char status[20];
};

int main() {
    struct leavedetails w;
    FILE *fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    FILE *fw = fopen("leavedetails.txt", "w");
    while (fread(&w, sizeof(struct leavedetails), 1, fp)) {
        fwrite(&w, sizeof(struct leavedetails), 1, fw);
    }
    fclose(fw);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

temp file:

> [image: temp file]

leave details file:

> [image: leave details file]

The structure in the temp file is not completely written into the leave details file.

Comment: Links are highly discouraged. Please post the code as well.

Comment: Post code & data here as text (or even better modify your code to hard-code your test data).  Also revise question: "What is wrong with my code" is a task not  a question.  You tell us what is wrong, and we can help you figure out why.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new to this and I had changed the format of my questions. Very appreciate for the advices.

Comment: How did you create temp.txt? If you did using some other code please post that code. It's hard to read the files from images but it seems the last struct in temp.txt is incomplete

Comment: Have you tried to open the files using "rb" and "wb" ?

Comment: What are the byte counts of both files? Are they the same?

Comment: We need a copy of the input file, not a picture of it, to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried "rb"and "wb"

Comment: May I know how to put the txt file in here?

Comment: I use the format of fwrite(&w,sizeof(struct leavedetails),1,fw); to create the temp file

Comment: Maybe host it somewhere and link it?  My answer generates the input with  leavebalance=0.  Does it work for you?  Just be careful it doesn't overwrite your source file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As the current temp.txt file seems small enough you could try to provide us an hexa dump of it: `with open('temp.txt', 'rb') as fd:  while True:    b = fd.read(1)  if b = b'': break   print(hex(b[0]),end = ' ')` (do not forget newlines and indentation...)

Comment: [Edit] and provide a _hex dump_ (google that) of both files, otherwise we cannot do much. How did you create the "temp.txt" file in the first place? Show a [mcve] that creates that file.

Comment: And modify your code slightly in order to print the return value of fread. And show what it prints

Comment: @Jabberwocky: `fread` will return either `0` or `1`, no extra information can be derived from this return value: if the record was fully read, partial read cannot be distinguished from end of file or read error.

Answer (score 3):

1. I cannot reproduce the problem maybe it's the missing "b" on a platform that cares about that?
2. (not fixed) Don't use the suffix .txt for binary files.
3. (not fixed) Consider reworking your struct to proper types at least for `leavefrom` (date), `reason` and `status` (`enum`s).  `char *` instead of fixed strings so you don't write junk to your files.
4. (not fixed) Prefer constants to magic values (10, 15, 20, 20).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct leavedetails {
    char staffid[10];
    char leavefrom[15];
    int leavebalance;
    char reason[20];
    char status[20];
};

int main() {
    struct leavedetails w;

    FILE *fp=fopen("temp.txt", "wb");
    if(!fp) {
         printf("fopen failed when trying to create input file\n");
         return 1;
    }
    fwrite(&(struct leavedetails) {"aa", "01/01/2023", 0, "Annual", "Pending"}, sizeof w, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&(struct leavedetails) {"dd", "03/03/2023", 0, "Annual", "Cancelled"}, sizeof w, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("temp.txt", "rb");
    if(!fp) {
         printf("fopen failed when trying to read input file\n");
         return 1;
    }
    FILE *fw=fopen("leavedetails.txt", "wb");
    if(!fw) {
         printf("fopen failed when trying to create output file\n");
         fclose(fp);
         return 1;
    }
    while(fread(&w, sizeof w, 1, fp))
        fwrite(&w, sizeof w, 1, fw);
    fclose(fw);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and the two files are identical:

```
$ cmp leavedetails.txt temp.txt
```